# Cannot access to sap.ui.getCore() when app is deployed Fiori sapui5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm working on a Fiori App in SAP Web IDE full stack. My application works totally fine in SAP Cloud Platform but when I deploy it to my SAP system in Fiori Launchpad, I get `sap.ui.getCore().byId(...) undefined`. So I change My use about `sap.ui` in order to avoid this error. My goal is to hide some `<li>` from my menu in the parent view App, I use then `document.getElementsByTagName("ul")` which works in SAP Cloud Platform but doesn't work neither when deployed. For me, I cannot access to my parent view's elements.
Thank you for helping me with this.

Answer (score 0):

You should never access anything by Id like you did. Also parent child componts in one app are usually a bad idea and pointless in a launchpad.

Anyhow, you didn't share how the "parent view app" (ui5 knows components, controller and fragments) relates to the child. But in any cases use a json model and bind a property of your choice in XML.

Models can be passed programmatically or are even passed automatically (e.g. i18n is basically a json model at component level). Access model in child and call

```
oView.getModel('myModel').setProperty("/isVisible', false)
```